# how to convert PDF file to swf programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdf2swf

I want to convert PDF file to .swf file using c#. I am using PDF2SWF with following parameters. It converts small files but faild for larg files..... say 4MB file(more than 20 pages).

Following are the parameters passed to convert.

p.StartInfo.FileName = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Tools/PDF2SWF.exe");
p.StartInfo.Arguments = sourceFile + " -o " + sourceFile.Replace(".pdf", "") + ".swf -T 9 -f";

Please suggest.

Comment: When it fails, do you get an error?

Comment: Does it work correctly if you run the command in command prompt?

Comment: process complete successfuly, but left no effect(do not create new file)

Comment: while running from command prompt, it gives error "This file is too complex to render- SWF only supports 65536 shapes at once"

Comment: Can u paste the Code which converts small files?